# Multiple concurrent perform() calls on same NSManagedObjectContext object

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

When multiple `perform()` calls are invoked on the same `NSManagedObjectContext` object, will they be executed one by one in the order they are invoked? I think this is true because [the document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) says

> Core Data uses thread (or serialized queue) confinement to protect
>   managed objects and managed object contexts (see Core Data Programming
>   Guide).

which suggests that managed object context and its thread has 1:1 mapping and all `perform()` calls are serial. But it scares me that I can't find any explicit discussion on this, not even in Apple's doc.

In my App, I set up a CoreData stack with `NSPersistentContainer` and create a dedicated background context for modifying managed objects. It could occur that when a `perform()` call is invoked, the previous `perform()` call hasn't finished yet. So it's critical that they are executed one by one in this case. That's why I'd like to confirm my understanding above.

**Note**: I understand `perform()` is asynchronous, but that's from the caller's perspective. What I'm asking about is from the callee's perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the multiple perform calls will be queued up and executed in that same order.